# configuration for php.ini file for example max_execution_limit

Tags: php, wordpress, server

i have an AWS Server with cloudways that hosts a learndash wordpress website, it has  16 vCPU and 32 GB ram, i had alot of issues on my server due to CPU just maxing out despite not having alot of users concurrently and upon resetting these values to default things became better

i would like to know how to optimize PHP configuration values for my server for example

```
max_execution_limit
upload_size
memory limit
max input variables
max input time
opache memory
```

or if can point me to the right direction on how to calculate these values for my server?

resetting it to default fixed the CPU maxing out  but i can't really observe if it increases performance or not